# How to extract part of IP address from string in Bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep, ip, extract

i try to get 2 last octets from IP address from diferents strings.
Some of them will have syntax like:

```
ABCD_192.192.111.123 or
ABCD_EFG_192.111.123.192
```

how can I grep in universal way only first part of string + 2 last octets from IP? e.g:

```
ABCD_111.123 or
ABCD_EFG_123.192
```

now i can only get IP

furthermore i need avoid using temp files.

Comment: The `*` and `"` are part of the textfile?

Comment: After seeing your profile @MichaoDev, got to know that you never select any answer as correct one, give it sometime and when you get some answers always try to select anyone of them as correct one(if it is solving  your question).Also we do encourage people on SO to add their efforts with their question too, so please try to add that in your questions, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bash to split the strings:

```
string="ABCD_192.192.111.123"
IFS=_. read -r prefix octet1 octet2 octet3 octet4 <<< "$string"
printf '%s_%s.%s\n' "$prefix" "$octet3" "$octet4"
```

Use this two step version instead. It can deal with prefixes with one or more underscores:

```
string="ABCD_EFG_192.192.111.123"
IFS=. read -r prefix_octet1 octet2 octet3 octet4 <<< "$string"
prefix=${prefix_octet1%_*}
printf '%s_%s.%s\n' "$prefix" "$octet3" "$octet4"
```

Comment: almost ok, but 
for

    `string="ABCD_EFG_192.192.111.123"`

i get

`ABCD_192.111.123`

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk '{sub(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\./,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure about your data, but this

```
$ echo '*"ABCD_192.192.111.123"
*"ABCD_EFG_192.111.123.192"' \|
grep -o '\*\"\([A-Z]*_\)*\([0-9]*.\)\{2\}'
```

produces this output and now if you need, you can pipe to `sed` to substitute the last dot with a `"`.

```
*"ABCD_192.192.
*"ABCD_EFG_192.111.
```

`sed 's/\.$/\"/'`.

So you could try:

```
grep -o '\*\"\([A-Z]*_\)*\([0-9]*.\)\{2\}' | sed 's/\.$/\"/'
```

Comment: thank you, but i get first 2 octets instead of 2 last octets from ip addresses

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -n -e 'while(/^([^0-9]+).*\.([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/g) {print "$1$2\n"}'
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.